# React Hook Form value is not changing when swapping or Deleting Groups

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm making a nested form builder that is dynamic.

This is the current project I'm working on: https://codesandbox.io/s/ava-dynamic-react-hook-form-ivgt40?file=/src/App.js

The issue I'm having is that when I swap or delete Groups, the values within the Group aren't properly set.

I believe it is due to the {...register()} and the altering ref on my Input Components, but I am not certain.

The form data.js file in the linked project at the top contains the form structure I wish to render.

```
list: {
    id,
    label,
    control: "list" // identifier that this element is a list
    creatable: boolean,
    items: [
        [elements], // group 1
        [elements], // group 2
    ]
}
```

```
input: {
    id,
    label,
    control: "input" // identifier that this element is a input
    type: "text" // type of input
    defaultValue,
    rules: {
        required: {
            value: boolean,
            message: string,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code sandbox link seems broken, It did work earlier and I was able to write an answer going by that.

Comment: oh yeah my bad sorry, i think i deleted it. Here the new Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/ava-dynamic-react-hook-form-builder-7vrxkz?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## State management

You seem to be mixing places to that are keeping tracking of state.

You basicly have 2 types of state

- State of the form values | this is stored in the `react-hook-form`
- State of the **sort order** of form inputs | this is stored in your `Element.jsx`

By mixing these, you have to manually make sure they stay in sync

## react-hook-form

When you're using `react-hook-form`. you're entrusting some state management to that hook.
They provide an API through **register** to keep track of the fields and values for the form.

Register takes a **name** as the first param.
This is the only handle you have for the form to identify fields.
**A new name would be a new fields.**

## the problem

You're not keeping things in sync.
Changing the order will do a couple of things:

- The current `elementIdPath` is something like  `Emailprofile.0.notifications.0.email.0.email-abcd123`
- `Emailprofile.0.notifications.0.email.0.email-abcd123` is passed as name to the register.
- click on the change order button
- `handleSwapListElements` runs and changes the element via `setElementItem`
- the `elementIdPath` changes: `Emailprofile.0.notifications.0.email.1.email-abcd123` (notice index change from 0 to 1)
- **New name is registerd** and treated as a new field
- the old field is also still registered and in state. clicking submit will also have the old name and value.

## The fix

Keep the sort order and values in sync. You'll have to decide yourself how exactly to do that.
either:

- don't include sort order or indexes as key in the name.
- manually keep things in sync using `react-hook-form` methods.

Both have their ups and downs.

### not including indexes as key

A dynamic form without indexes would require you to attach all that information on the field itself.
Basically you would register a unique key (uuid), and keep track of the uuid path yourself.
IE you register to properties.:

```
 {
   "abcd123-value" : "some@email.de",
   "abcd123-path"  : "Emailprofile.0.notifications.0.email.0.email-abcd123" // this would not be shown to the user, but still exposed to the form, in the submit you would manually combine the information again. 
 }
```

### manually keep things in sync using `react-hook-form` methods.

Whenever you change the `name` of a field, you would get the current value.
unregister the old name and set the value on the new name.
`react-hook-form` exposes a method from the hook for that.

[unregister](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/unregister)
and [setValue](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/setvalue)

If it where up to me, and seeing your code.I would probably try to go in this direction as opposed to refactoring to things to remove the indexes from name.

#### sandbox

this [sandbox with modifications](https://codesandbox.io/s/ava-dynamic-react-hook-form-builder-forked-58npl0?file=/src/components/Element.jsx) should paint the picture.
It will not properly work yet for the base elements, but the nodes at `profile.0.notification.0.email` should function.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer! Ill try it like this, thanks a lot :)

Comment: I've added a sandbox link,

Comment: thanks for the work :) i also see a rlly big problem atm. When swaping the Groups i also have to unregister all nested elements in a Group. And when i have multiple elements in a Group its still buggy when swapping.
I dont rlly have an idea how i would fix this. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: i´ve updated my codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/ava-dynamic-react-hook-form-builder-7vrxkz?file=/src/components/inputs/Input.jsx
i found a way to unregister all elements in my Group. Thanks to your way :)
The only buggy thing is that some of my templates not getting a uuid.